# Not able to make multiple ajax calls inside one script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Ist i have an ajax call to autopopulate all fields based on a dropdown . Then i need to call the second ajax function on clicking update button. But when I am keeping Multiple ajax calls none of the calls are working. please help.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var selected;
        //alert('jquery works');
        $('#selectUsers').change(function(){
            selected = $('#selectUsers').val();
            //alert($('#selectUsers').val());
              $.ajax({
                url: "CustServlet2",
                type: "Post",
                data: {"selectUsers":selected},
                success : function(data)
                    {
                        //alert("Returned data"+ data);
                        var myarr = data.split(" ");
                        $('#cid').val(myarr[0]);
                        $('#csn').val(myarr[2]);
                        $('#req').val(myarr[3]);
                        $('#loc').val(myarr[4]);
                        $('#dtid').val(myarr[5]);
                        $('#dt').val(myarr[6]);
                        $('#dltid').val(myarr[7]);
                        $('#dltn').val(myarr[8]);
                        $('#dpo').val(myarr[9]);
                        $('#dao').val(myarr[10]);
                        $('#rbid').val(myarr[11]);
                        $('#rbn').val(myarr[12]);
                        $('#prid').val(myarr[13]);
                        $('#prn').val(myarr[14]);
                        $('#sid').val(myarr[15]);
                        $('#sn').val(myarr[16]);
                        $('#comments').val(myarr[17]);
                        $('#cci').val(myarr[18]);
                        $('#aci').val(myarr[19]);


                    }
                });
        });
         $("#submit").click(function(){
            //e.preventDefault();
            alert("submit alert");
            var cn1= $('#selectUsers').val();
            var csn1= $('#csn').val();
            var req1= $('#req').val();
            var loc1= $('#loc').val();
            var dltid1= $('#dltid').val();
            var dtid1= $('#dtid').val();
            var rbid1= $('#rbid').val();
            var prid1= $('#prid').val();
            var cci1= $('#cci').val();
            var aci1= $('#aci').val();
            var dpo1= $('#dpo').val();
            var dao1= $('#dao').val();
            var sid1= $('#sid').val();

            alert();
               $.ajax({             

                 url: "CustServlet3",
                type: "Post",
                data: {"selectUsers":cn1 "csn":csn1 "req":req1 "loc":loc1 "dltid":dltid1 "dtid":dtid1 "rbid":rbid1 "prid":prid1 "cci":cci1 "aci":aci1 "dpo":dpo1 "dao":dao1 "sid":sid1},
                success : function(data)
                    {
                    if(data.equals(1)){alert("profile updated successfully !!")}
                    if(data.equals(0)){alert("profile not updated !!")}
                    }//for success 

                });//for ajax2  
        });//for click   
    });


 </script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working >?

Comment: are you getting any error in console

Comment: remove alert inside ajax

Comment: Im not getting any error msg. The autopopulate function wch is supposed to work with ist ajax call is not happening. also no response from the submit button wch is supposed to work with second call.

Comment: @saravanann ok!!!! when i removed the alert inside ajax, partial output came.

Comment: now im having error in second ajax function. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

prevent the default click so your ajax can complete & remove the alert from the ajax body

```
 $("#submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            statname = $('#sn').val();
            alert("statname" +statname);
               $.ajax({             
                 url: "CustServlet3",
                type: "Post",
                data: {sn:statname},
                success : function(data)
                    {
                    if(data.equals(1)){alert("profile updated successfully !!")}
                    if(data.equals(0)){alert("profile not updated !!")}
                    }//for success 

                });//for ajax2  
        });//for click  
    });
```

Comment: Thank u for answering. I made the change, removed alert. I had a type mismatch error then. I added all the fields of the table in database now. before i had added only one field, hence the type mismatch occured. So now i corrected the number of fields and also removed the alert. but I still have the same problem. Both scripts not loading..

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove alert from ajax options

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
        alert("submit alert"); 
        statname = $('#sn').val();
        alert("statname" +statname);
           $.ajax({             
            alert("ajax working alert"); // Remove this alert from here you cant add alert in between of ajax Options as its Json Object 
             url: "CustServlet3",
            type: "Post",
            data: {"sn":statname},
            success : function(data)
                {
                if(data.equals(1)){alert("profile updated successfully !!")}
                if(data.equals(0)){alert("profile not updated !!")}
                }//for success 

            });//for ajax2  
    });
```

Comment: I see that you are posting invalid json 

 `{"selectUsers":cn1 "csn":csn1 "req":req1 "loc":loc1 "dltid":dltid1 "dtid":dtid1 "rbid":rbid1 "prid":prid1 "cci":cci1 "aci":aci1 "dpo":dpo1 "dao":dao1 "sid":sid1}`

need to add comma in between 


`{"selectUsers":cn1 ,"csn":csn1, "req":req1 ,"loc":loc1, "dltid":dltid1 ,"dtid":dtid1 ,"rbid":rbid1, "prid":prid1, "cci":cci1, "aci":aci1, "dpo":dpo1 ,"dao":dao1, "sid":sid1}`

Comment: OK, Thank you for that correction.  I tried running the code ,even then no response from both ajax functions

Comment: sorry I had missed a comma.Finally output came. Thank you so much for helping